# How can I validate if the value is overlapping using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to check if the the timelineArray[1] and timelineArray[2] got overlapped or not. If its overlapped then add increment by timelineArray[3], if not the value should start with 1.

```
var timelineArray = [
  ["name1", "384", "456", "30"],
  ["name2", "72", "192", "30"],
  ["name3", "384", "456", "30"],
  ["name4", "384", "456", "15"],
  ["name5", "384", "576", "30"],
  ["name6", "96", "240", "12"]
  ["name7", "384", "456", "12"]
  ["name7", "384", "456", "12"]
  ["name8", "1", "10", "20"]
];
```

I have updated my code, here is my current code:

```
function checkTimelineOverlap(timelineArray) {
  let result = [];
  let currentStart = 1;
  let currentEnd = 0;
  let lastIncrement = 0; // Initialize lastIncrement to 0

  for (let i = 0; i < timelineArray.length; i++) {
    const [name, start, end, increment] = timelineArray[i];
    startNum = parseInt(start);
    endNum = parseInt(end);
    incrementNum = parseInt(increment);

    let overlapNames = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      const [prevName, prevStart, prevEnd, prevIncrement] = timelineArray[j]; // Add prevIncrement here
      if (
        (startNum >= parseInt(prevStart) && startNum <= parseInt(prevEnd)) ||
        (endNum >= parseInt(prevStart) && endNum <= parseInt(prevEnd)) ||
        (startNum <= parseInt(prevStart) && endNum >= parseInt(prevEnd))
      ) {
        overlapNames.push(prevName);
        lastIncrement = parseInt(prevIncrement); // Store the increment value of the last overlapping event
      }
    }

    let overlapMessage =
      overlapNames.length > 0 ? `overlap with ${overlapNames.join(", ")}` : "no overlap";

    if (overlapNames.length > 0) {
      currentEnd += lastIncrement; // Use the lastIncrement to update currentEnd
      currentStart = lastIncrement + 1;
    } else {
      // Update both currentStart and currentEnd when there's no overlap
      currentStart = 1;
      currentEnd = currentStart + incrementNum - 1;
    }

    result.push(`${name}, ${overlapMessage}, ${currentStart}-${currentEnd}`);

    // Reset lastIncrement for the next iteration
    lastIncrement = 0;
  }

  return result;
}

var timelineArray = [
  ["name1", "384", "456", "30"],
  ["name2", "72", "192", "30"],
  ["name3", "384", "456", "30"],
  ["name4", "384", "456", "15"],
  ["name5", "384", "576", "30"],
  ["name6", "96", "240", "12"],
  ["name7", "384", "456", "12"],
  ["name8", "1", "3", "12"]
];

const result = checkTimelineOverlap(timelineArray);
console.log(result);
```

My current result is:

```
1. name1, no overlap, 1-30
2. name2, no overlap, 1-30
3. name3, overlap with name1, 31-60
4. name4, overlap with name1, name3, 31-90
5. name5, overlap with name1, name3, name4, 16-105
6. name6, overlap with name2, 31-135
7. name7, overlap with name1, name3, name4, name5, 31-165
8. name8, no overlap, 1-12
```

Excepted result I should get is:

```
 1. name1, no overlap, 1-30
 2. name2, no overlap, 1-30
 3. name3, overlap with name1, 31-60
 4. name4, overlap with name1 and name3 , 61-75
 5. name5, overlap with name1,name3 and name4, 76-105
 6. name6, overlap with name2, 31-42
 7. name7, overlap with name1,name3,name4 and name5, 106-118
 8. name8, no overlap, 1-12
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the expected results, you can use the following JavaScript code to loop through the timelineArray and check for overlaps while keeping track of the current timeline range. Here's a function that does that

```js
function checkTimelineOverlap(timelineArray) {
  let result = [];
  let currentStart = 1;
  let currentEnd = 1;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < timelineArray.length; i++) {
    const [name, start, end, increment] = timelineArray[i];
    startNum = parseInt(start);
    endNum = parseInt(end);
    incrementNum = parseInt(increment);

    let overlapNames = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      const [prevName, prevStart, prevEnd] = timelineArray[j];
      if ((startNum >= parseInt(prevStart) && startNum <= parseInt(prevEnd)) || 
          (endNum >= parseInt(prevStart) && endNum <= parseInt(prevEnd)) || 
          (startNum <= parseInt(prevStart) && endNum >= parseInt(prevEnd))) {
        overlapNames.push(prevName);
      }
    }

    let overlapMessage = overlapNames.length > 0 ? `overlap with ${overlapNames.join(", ")}` : "no overlap";

    if (overlapNames.length > 0) {
      currentEnd += incrementNum;
    } else {
      currentStart = currentEnd + 1;
      currentEnd = currentStart + incrementNum - 1;
    }

    result.push(`${name}, ${overlapMessage}, ${currentStart}-${currentEnd}`);
  }

  return result;
}

var timelineArray = [
  ["name1", "384", "456", "30"],
  ["name2", "72", "192", "30"],
  ["name3", "384", "456", "30"],
  ["name4", "384", "456", "15"],
  ["name5", "384", "576", "30"],
  ["name6", "96", "240", "12"],
  ["name7", "384", "456", "12"]
];

const result = checkTimelineOverlap(timelineArray);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The increment result after first element all start by 32. Can continue the increment based on the previous end value?